# "Post lunch" or "after lunch" which is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I use to use "post lunch" to inform a person about fixing up the meeting time if it is in the afternoon office time. apart from that I have never used it in any of other conversation.

recently, In British council website I read the following sentence " You will also have a chance to interact with our expert teacher who will help you identify your English learning requirements, **post** this you can enrol for a course that suits your requirement."

In the above sentence post is used. If the same information, if I would have written, I would have used "After". since the above sentence is from British council, definitely they are right.

My question now is, Can I interchangeably use after and post? or is Post and after has got a different meaning and should be used appropriately? if so, How can I trigger myself choosing the right word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**After** and **post** are often interchangeable. The latter tends to have a more formal tone. So I would tend to say "a post lunch meeting" but "an after lunch nap". Post can also more strongly imply an era -- "post World War II Germany" sounds much better than "after World War II Germany" or even the more grammatical "Germany after World War II".

In your example of "*... identify your English learning requirements, **post** this ...*", I agree with your gut feeling.  **After** flows better than **post**, which to my ears sounds stuffy and overly formal.

As far as a general rule, **after** is more common. If you feel that you are identifying an era, choose **post**. Also, **post** would sometimes work better if you are striving for formality. (As your example shows, the formality can go too far.)

I am American, so this answer may not fit well in the UK or Commonwealth nations.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just being the British council doesn't make them right. There is a campaign to convince officials to use clear English http://www.plainenglish.co.uk. This site exists because sometimes officials use hard to understand overly formal language.

As a UK resident and native English speaker, I can confirm that the natural British English for this would either be "after this" or possibly "following this". I don't think I've ever heard the word post used in this context.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Welcome to ELL! It's usually quite helpful to the OP to explain the reasoning behind the word you've chosen, as well as providing a source.